# How to set className without {styles.red} in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

#### Description

I want to use only the pure name of the class without {styles.class-name} convention in Next.js, I google it and find I need to configure the next.config.js file. So, have someone good references for this?

#### I have this:

And it works fine in Next.js

[image: first-one]

#### And need this:

This is not working by default in Next.js

[image: second]

Comment: Please just copy the code into your question. Screen shots are harder to reference in answers. The editor lets you format your code with the `{}` button, or create an executable snippet with the `<>` button.

Comment: In what way does this fail?  Does the resulting HTML element have `class="red"`?  Does the CSS have a class by that name?  What specifically happens in this attempt?

Comment: Why do you need the later variant? The earlier variant guaranties encapsulation of the style but not the later.

Comment: @CharlesBamford there is no my code, this is from youtube : [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nyB7MlYo1v0)

Comment: @David yes it has, yes CSS has a class by that name, and nothing at all happened, CSS does not apply.

Comment: @OluwafemiSule this is a request from the client, and I just want to know how to do it. What are also props and cons?

Answer (score 0):

Next.js has globals.css file and it's in styles folder so you can make:

`className="red"`

and then in globals.css file:

```
.red{
//...
}
```

But I recommend you to use ***.module.css*** files because it's cleaner and doesn't make a mess.

Comment: That is not what I want, I want to use modules.

Answer (score 0):

#### UPDATE:

I hadn't checked this earlier. You can directly use [`babel-plugin-react-css-modules`](https://github.com/gajus/babel-plugin-react-css-modules).

---

#### Ignore the content below

I had earlier wrote a Babel plugin for this. It is not robust, can be improved, but does the job:

```js
// babel-plugin-cx.js

const __path = require('path');

const plugin = ({ types: t }) => {
  const cloneNode = t.cloneNode || t.cloneDeep;

  return {
    name: 'babel-plugin-cx',
    visitor: {
      Program: {
        enter(path, state) {
          state.stylesIdentifier = path.scope.generateUidIdentifier('styles');
        },

        exit(path, state) {
          if (state.hasProp) {
            const importDeclaration = t.importDeclaration(
              [t.importDefaultSpecifier(state.stylesIdentifier)],
              t.stringLiteral(
                __path
                  .parse(state.file.opts.filename)
                  .name.toLowerCase()
                  .replace(/^([^]*)$/, state.opts.pathReplace),
              ),
            );

            path.node.body.unshift(importDeclaration);
          }
        },
      },

      JSXAttribute(path, state) {
        if (path.node.name.name !== state.opts.propName) return;

        if (
          state.opts.ignoredElements.includes(
            path.findParent((p) => p.isJSXOpeningElement()).node.name.name,
          )
        )
          return;

        path.node.name.name = 'className';
        const value = path.get('value');

        if (value.isLiteral()) {
          value.replaceWith(
            t.jsxExpressionContainer(
              t.memberExpression(
                cloneNode(state.stylesIdentifier),
                cloneNode(value.node),
                true,
                false,
              ),
            ),
          );

          state.hasProp = true;
        } else if (value.isJSXExpressionContainer()) {
          const expression = value.get('expression');
          expression.replaceWith(
            t.memberExpression(
              cloneNode(state.stylesIdentifier),
              cloneNode(expression.node),
              true,
              false,
            ),
          );

          state.hasProp = true;
        }
      },

      JSXSpreadAttribute(path, state) {
        if (
          state.opts.ignoredElements.includes(
            path.findParent((p) => p.isJSXOpeningElement()).node.name.name,
          )
        )
          return;

        const argument = path.get('argument');
        if (!argument.isObjectExpression()) return;
        const properties = argument.get('properties');

        for (const property of properties) {
          if (property.node.key.name === state.opts.propName) {
            property.node.key.name = 'className';
            const value = property.get('value');
            value.replaceWith(
              t.memberExpression(
                cloneNode(state.stylesIdentifier),
                cloneNode(value.node),
                true,
                false,
              ),
            );

            state.hasProp = true;
          }
        }
      },
    },
  };
};

module.exports = plugin;
```

```
// .babelrc

{
  "presets": ["next/babel"],
  "plugins": [
    [
      "./babel-plugin-cx",
      {
        "pathReplace": "./$1.module.css",
        "propName": "cx",
        "ignoredElements": ["circle", "ellipse", "radialGradient"]
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

If using Typescript, you need to add this (also add this file to `includes` array in `tsconfig.json`:

```
// custom.d.ts

import type * as React from 'react';

declare module 'react' {
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/consistent-type-definitions, @typescript-eslint/no-unnecessary-qualifier
  interface HTMLAttributes<T> extends React.DOMAttributes<T> {
    cx?: string;
  }
}
```

After this, you can simply write:

```
<div cx="red">Red text!</div>
```

There is no need to import the module file. It will be automatically imported if necessary from the specified `"pathReplace"` option. (`$1` indicates the file name using the `cx` attribute).

`pathReplace` example:

`@styles/_$1.module.scss` : if file using `cx` is `Component.tsx` then the styles will be imported from module `@styles/_component.module.scss`.

You can configure the `propName` using the provided option. You will also need to change `next-env.d.ts` accordingly. And, change the `ignoredElements` option accordingly, as your attribute name may be same as some attribute defined in the JSX/HTML standard.

**Caveats:**

- The plugin currently completely ignores `className` attribute if `cx` is set on the element/component, i.e., if you need to merge with some global class name then use `` className={`global ${styles.red}`} ``.
- More than one class in `cx` is not supported. Can be implemented easily, but I was quite lazy.
- Spread attribute is only partially supported:

  ```
  // supported:
  <div {...{cx: "red", other: "attribute"}}>Red text!</div>

  // not supported:
  const attrs = {cx: "red", other: "attribute"};
  <div {...attrs}>Red text!</div>
  ```

  You may like to configure this rule in ESLint [`react/jsx-props-no-spreading`](https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/blob/master/docs/rules/jsx-props-no-spreading.md).