# Why use module vs regular CSS in NextJS?

Tags: next.js

I used `npx create-next-app` to start a new app. I realized that `_app.tsx` just pulls in a regular CSS file via `import "../../styles/globals.css";`.

A specific page over at `index.tsx` used a module like `import styles from "../../styles/Home.module.css";` followed by `<h1 className={styles.title}>`. Is there a specific reason it would be done this way? Inside `_app.tsx` I want to add something like `<div className="nav-wrapper">` but I'm not sure if best practice using this system is to do that vs `<div className={styles.navWrapper}>` when outside a specific module.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost everything that you do using CSS modules can be done by using global CSS. But there are some caveats in the latter:

- There is a risk of overlapping CSS in global stylesheets – Suppose you wrote some styles under a selector. Later, you forgot that you had written any such thing and used the same selector to define different styles.

  You'd end up finding where the bug is, why the styles are not being properly applied. This is a slightly harder problem to debug when you have conflicting styles with some third party library, or a component that you haven't written.

  This scenario can be completely avoided by using CSS modules, as during compiling the selectors are hashed, hence they are scope-limited.
- If your app has multiple pages and you're using global CSS which adds rules for some page-specific components, you will have unused CSS. This will effect your page speed.

CSS modules on the other hand have certain issues as well. The major one is that you will have to write more code, especially if you are toggling classes using JS. [I had wrote a babel plugin earlier to reduce some of the code typing.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68045052/11613622)

---

Regarding best practices -

If your style is meant to be shared by all the pages, then it is safe to put them in global stylesheet. What you are trying to do falls under this category. You are probably trying to implement some kind of persistent layout between page changes. Using CSS modules will not do anything additional in this particular case, except for hashing the class names.