# How to use scss without css modules in nextjs

Tags: reactjs, sass, next.js

I can configure webpack to allow includes of scss.

***Note:** Working with classNames on the original html is faster when copying code between static html to React components, which is why I want to do it this way.*

How to make this work in nextjs **without css modules and styled components** and **just using basic scss and classnames?**

```js
import 'styles/MyComponent.scss';

const MyComponent = () => {
  return (
    <div className="someClass">
      stuff..
    </div>
  );
};

export default MyComponent;
```

Comment: Import that stylesheet in `_app`? Ref: [Adding a Global Stylesheet](https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/built-in-css-support#adding-a-global-stylesheet), or maybe do something like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68531573, or this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68045052

Answer (score 11):

1. install sass

```bash
npm install --save-dev sass
```

2. Disable css-modules component styling in Next.js

In the `next.config.js`, add the following config:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const path = require('path');
const nextConfig = {
  // disable css-modules component styling
  webpack(config) {
    config.module.rules.forEach((rule) => {
      const { oneOf } = rule;
      if (oneOf) {
        oneOf.forEach((one) => {
          if (!`${one.issuer?.and}`.includes('_app')) return;
          one.issuer.and = [path.resolve(__dirname)];
        });
      }
    })
    return config;
  },
}

module.exports = nextConfig
```

Verified in next.js version: v12.3~v13.x

See example: No CSS modules in next.js app: ([json5 app](https://json-5.com/jsontots))
[image: No CSS modules in next.js]

Comment: Doesn't answer how to use scss, but it is an interesting idea, to extend/overwrite the nextjs webpack config. Maybe I can just add in an additional handler for importing scss.

Comment: @SteveTomlin I hava updated how to use scss in next.js.

Comment: You are my hero.

Answer (score -2):

You could do that with the withSass() function provided @zeit/next-sass plugin but it is now deprecated.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@zeit/next-sass

Comment: Thanks but if its deprecated is no good unless I downgrade, which is not ideal. Webpack is still the better option here